# How to return a Typescript class return as oneliner

Tags: typescript

Hi have a class and use an interface

```
interface myInterface {
    readonly exp: number;
    readonly iat: number;
    readonly auth_time: number;
    readonly jti: string;

}

export class MyClass {
    static async scope(token: string): Promise<any> {
        const scope: myInterface = await jwt_decode(token);
        return scope;
    }
}
```

how can i make

```
        const scope: myInterface = await jwt_decode(token);
        return scope;
```

as a oneliner?

Thanks in advance. Any help is welcome.

Comment: You marked the function to return `any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need anything special, just specify the return type of the method:

```
static async scope(token: string): Promise<myInterface> {
  return await jwt_decode(token);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `as` keyword to cast the typing of variable `scope` from `ReturnType<typeof jwt_decode>` to `myInterface` by:

```js
static async scope(token: string) {
  return await jwt_decode(token) as myInterface;
}
```

Or you could even write it like this by arrow function:

```js
static scope = (token: string) => jwt_decode(token) as Promise<myInterface>;
```

Comment: The problem with `as` is that it bypasses typechecking, unlike the OP's code.

Comment: assertion is not the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

In Typescript 4.9 (not released yet) you may be able to use the new `satisfies` keyword.

```
static async scope(token: string): Promise<myInterface> {
  return await jwt_decode(token) satisfies myInterface;
}
```

Unlike `as`, it does perform typechecking, but it doesn't change the inferred type (unlike in your example). But by specifying that the method returns a `Promise<myInterface>`, you get the correct type anyway.

Comment: How the OP will use a TS version feature which is not yet released?

Comment: Maybe they are happy to use the beta version, or maybe this answer will help someone else in the future having the same problem.

Comment: Using beta version is not recommended at all. LTS version uses are recommended only if you wish to work with latest.

Comment: Surely some people do like using beta versions, otherwise they wouldn't exist at all.